# Node.js: How can I clone an object with Underscore and assign new properties to the clone afterwards?

Tags: node.js, clone, express, mongoose, underscore.js

I'm working on a REST API with node and express. I'm using mongoose.js, and I am creating a new user document in my db. No sweat, works great.

The problem arises when I want to add a property to the json object that the .save() returns. I want to add this property after the save because it's a flag to the client consuming the REST interface, but it's not something I want to save to the db.

Here's my example:

```
var _ = require('underscore');    
var user = new User({"username" : "Joe"});
user.save(function(err, newuser){
  if (err) return next(err);
  var nu = _.clone(newuser);
  nu.newbie = 'true';
  res.send(JSON.stringify(nu));
});
```

Here's an example response (this is what's in `nu` ) :

```
{
"username": "Joe",
"_id": "4f343383a5503c452a000002",
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to add the property `nu.newbie` and set it to `true` and it's not working. I believe this is a scope or reference issue of some kind. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give an example of the bad response? By not working do you mean the property 'newbie' is missing entirely or only the value is missing? Is the rest of 'newuser' making it to the response?

Comment: Can't see any reason why it shouldn't work (although you don't need to quote `true`, unless you truly intend to encode it as the string "true")

Comment: @XHR Added the example response to the original post. newbie is missing entirely.

Comment: @Flambino Right, true doesn't need the quotes, not that it matters for this test.

Comment: Code looks fine and I can make it work in my environment. Are you sure the confusion is not somewhere else? Note you could also use _.defaults to do this in one line. http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#defaults

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the object returned by save is not a "raw" javascript object. Its wrapped by mongoose and has its methods on there. When you clone, you also clone the mongoose stuff!

When a mongoose object is sent down by res.send, it is serialized, and mongoose only serializes the members of the objects that it is aware of. If you want to add properties, you need to do it on a "raw" javascript object. Like so:

```
var nu = newuser.toJSON();
nu.newbie = 'true';
res.json(nu);
```

also, res.json is just a nice shorthand that will take care of converting to json and setting the content type.